# Green vs black capacitor (aluminum)

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

I seem to have defective capacitors on a board and I am looking at buying new one to change them.

The actual capacitors are green.  I noticed that the green ones are more expensive than the black ones (same voltage same capacitance) so I was wondering if there was a difference between them.

[image]

Comment: Other than the color? Could be, no way for us to know.  There could be other important parameters like ESR, ripple current rating, temperature rating etc. that may or may not be important in your application.  When in doubt, replace with the exact same part number from the same manufacturer.

Comment: Do you happen to have part numbers or other technical details that might be different? As far as I know, the color of the electrolytic capacitor does not follow any standard code/pattern/table that could provide info.

Comment: There are many other more important parameters than colour of a capacitor. In some cases I've seen bipolar electrolytics that were significantly distinctive green in colour. But you need to know what do the capacitors do in the circuit. You can likely read capacitor capacitance and voltage rating on it, and determine polarity if it's not bipolar. But you can't determine if it needs to be a low ESR capacitor by looking at it, you need to figure out the part number and seek for a matching component, or to determine if any generic will do. If the capacitors are even broke and need changing.

Comment: They were in the power supp’u board of an old computer monitor. 

I guess they are smoothing capacitor (they were a bunch (lile 5-6) or them next to each other

Comment: What manufacturer are the replacement ones? Some no-name manufacturer is going to be cheaper than Rubycon, Nichicon, etc. And if you buy no-name capacitors from amazon or ebay or whatever, you have a good chance of paying ten times or more the market price for *good* ones from a proper distributor, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no correlation between the color of the shrink wrap insulation and the performance of the capacitor across manufacturers. Some may like green with gold printing, others black and white. Some may use different colors for different model lines. You need to look at model numbers and specifications as well as the voltage and temperature rating on the capacitor. And some manufacturers are thought to be better than others.

Key specifications:

1. Capacitance (same or a *little* bit higher is fine) generally marked clearly
2. Voltage rating  (same or a bit higher is fine) generally marked clearly
3. Temperature rating  (this translates to life span in most cases) generally marked clearly
4. Low impedance vs. standard (if they're bulging caps on a mombo they likely need to be low impedance) usually **not** marked
5. Size (if you want it to fit an existing board)

There are other things like bipolar vs. non-polar vs. standard (rare for the former two types to be in an application where they fail in bunches), polymer electrolytic types etc.

If you can't find any specifications for the part in the board (there are a great many makers of electrolytic capacitors and only a handful have good datasheets in English easily available) post some clear photos of the caps and a wider angle shot of the application (and a description) and we can probably provide some advice, maybe even good advice.

If the device is very old (20-30 years, say) even good quality replacement parts may be surprisingly small by comparison with the originals.

Comment: I added a picture of the capacitor to my original question

Answer (score -2):

Yes, green capacitors can works at high frequency. For example, inside little usb chargers or mainboards. They are more expensive.

Comment: Miguel - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the site rules in the [tour] & [help] as they differ from typical forums. (b) We expect answers to explain *why* they are the answer to the original question. Please can you [edit] your answer to explain why you state that "green capacitors can works at high frequency" and, since the question is about the difference to black capacitors, then why are you implying that black & green capacitors behave differently, just because of their colour? Without further explanation from you, this answer seems more like an opinion or guess. Thanks